# 10 + 1 − 2 = 9 X

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, pattern, lateral-thinking, language

> ## 10 + 1 − 2 = 9 X

Can you solve the puzzle in this expression?

---

- You must *only* replace the '**X**' to solve this puzzle.
- You *must not* add, remove, rearrange or modify any of the other characters.
- **'X**' represents *only one single digit* number.
- No maths is required.
- The solution relates to [language](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/language/info), [patterns](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/pattern/info) and [lateral thinking](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/lateral-thinking/info).

---

**Hint**

> A puzzle that heavily depends on linguistic features; **for instance
>  it may concern foreign languages, or only work in some particular
>  language**, or be built around a peculiarity of the English language.
>
> (The summary above was taken from the Wiki excerpt for the 'language' tag)

Comment: Only one answer has the right number but it doesn't have the solution I'm looking for. Again the tags are particularly important, especially 'pattern', 'lateral-thinking' and 'language'. A lot of people are missing the 'pattern' part.

Comment: Is the answer you have in mind *definitely more satisfactory* than the other answers that have been given? I mean, would someone seeing your intended solution say "Ah, yes, that definitely solves it" in a way they wouldn't in response to any of the others?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan That is a good point and it's something I have considered. There have been some good answers so far but I have not seen one that matches all the criteria given in the question and the tags used. It is difficult to tell you for sure without giving the answer away.

Comment: In light of the correct answer, would the [tag:knowledge] tag be appropriate? Anyone without knowledge of that particular... system... would never be able to solve this.

Comment: @Lolgast I think (like my last question) the language tag should cover it.

Comment: I misinterpreted "language" to be more along the lines of "wordplay". Perhaps both "language" and "knowledge" would've been better?

Comment: As others have said, the puzzle is not an equation, nor is it a "solved equation", whatever that means. It would better asked as "find the next character in this sequence". The tags were useful however. It's a great puzzle though, just posed in a misleading manner.

Comment: X = (10 + 1 − 2)/9 = 1 would be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Guess:

> X = 九

because

> In Chinese:
>  10 is 十,
>  1  is 一,
>  2  is 二,
>  The 'equation' is translating from Arabic numbers to Chinese
>
>  [image]

Comment: Correct! I am not sure why this answer was downvoted...

Comment: This has a bit of the [xkcd 169](https://xkcd.com/169/) about it. I mean, the puzzle says the thing is an equation and it isn't; it includes a bunch of deliberately incorrect symbols (none of the symbols as shown in the original "equation" is correct); the final answer isn't really something anyone would write (you'd present things in a more systematic order, no?). It's clever, I guess, but I'm not left thinking "yup, that's definitely a satisfying solution". (I didn't downvote the answer; my whingeing is about the *puzzle*.)

Comment: I had absolutely no intention of making the puzzle misleading, it is a shame it came across that way. I appreciate your feedback and I would like to discuss more about the puzzle in the chat if you have the time.

Comment: This is actually awesome haha, nice job TWhelan!  My suggestion to OP (Ambo100) is that, if you want to make the question even less misleading, try to handwrite the equation on a piece of paper and pose as a picture

Comment: Very clever answer... question to me seems like it could be excellent with some work.  As a 25-year reader of Japanese, I don't see + - = as numerals: the font utterly differentiates them.  As another reader has suggested, though, a handwritten list of 10 十 1 一 2 二 9 X would be fair enough, given that handwriting could be unclear enough to admit of either interpretation.  Or, use a screenshot of a (sans serif?) font and size where using the actual characters could be taken by most viewers for mathematical signs.  In other words have the right glyphs but count on them being misread.

Comment: @Alex  That was actually my original thought and I regret that I didn’t do it that way. My worry was that people would read-in too much about the other parts of the paper.

Comment: FWIW, I agree that a hand-written version of this could be much better.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan [This](https://i.imgur.com/NP0xTwG.jpg) is how I was going to write the puzzle but I've added a grid to show more clearly what part of the puzzle is missing. It think it is a lot closer to the idea I was going for.

Answer (score 47):

I think we can use:

> superscript 1

Where

> $10 + 1 − 2 = 9^1 = 9$

and it is also a single digit number from Super Hint #1 (or Super 'add criteria' #1)

Comment: If you want, here it is: ¹

Comment: @Manuel here we go you tiny one.  Thanks Manuel

Answer (score 18):

Replace the 'X' with

> 1

Explanation

> 91 is ninety one, or nine D one, or 9d1 in dice notation, which would equal 9

Comment: I like this because the `lateral-thinking` and `language` tags are relevant

Answer (score 12):

Is it

> 2

Because

> Ten plus one minus two is equal to nine **too**.
>  Or, ten plus one minus two is equal to nine, **true**.

Comment: This is an interesting solution but it is not the right answer. This could be the answer to the puzzle "One plus one equals two (too)" for example or any other sum resulting in two. The exact numbers and operators used in this puzzle are very important.

Answer (score 11):

> X is zero. A really small zero that is - so small it's actually a decimal point.

Answer (score 7):

> According to statement that is
> 10+1-2 = 9X
> it means
> 10+1-2 = 9*x
> now you can only replace x with 1 and answer statement is
> 10+1-2 = 9*1

Answer (score 6):

Considering the lateral thinking tag:

> X is 0

Explanation:

> As we can *replace* X
>  10 + 1 − 2 = 9 X becomes 10 + 1 − 2 = 09 which is true. We replace its value and its position.

Comment: Might run afoul of the "single-digit" rule, depending on one's interpretatin

Comment: You must not add, remove, rearrange or modify any of the existing characters, only 'X' can be replaced.

Comment: @Ambo100, that's not what your question states. "You must not add, remove, rearrange or modify any of the existing characters, apart from 'X'"  That means you can remove, rearrange and/or modify X"

Comment: Sorry, I have clarified the question. The first point as it was before does state that the only change you can make is to replace 'X'.

Comment: I think re-place (in other words, "move") could be a reasonable word-play re-reading of replace.

Answer (score 4):

Could the answer be...

> X = 9?

Reasoning:

> <strike>10 + 1 could be interpreted as 10 and 1 being concatenated into 101, then subtracting 2 gives you 99.</strike>
>
>  Now that math has been ruled out, maybe it's 9 because there are 9 syllables in "10 plus 1 minus 2 equals 9"?

Comment: I like the second solution because it uses the lateral thinking and language aspect, although it is still missing a clear pattern.

Answer (score 4):

I feel like this is a super stretch but I'm going to propose it anyway.

I believe the solution for X is:

> 9

My thinking was:

> The tags indicated language, pattern and lateral thinking. In addition, the fact that math isn't used here, I tried to not think about the numbers and symbols as math operations themselves. I decided to try and write out the line in words, seeing if I could use synonyms to try and find a pattern in the spelling that would indicate a solution.

So, I wrote:

> ten (10) net (+) one (1) no (-) two (2) out (=) nine (9) ____

I noticed:

> "Ten" reversed is "net". "One" reversed is close to "no". "Two" reversed is phonetically similar to "out". And, finally, "nine" reversed is close to "nine".

Comment: A lot of the points you covered in your thinking is very good, in particular the part about not seeing the symbols as maths operators. The answer however is, as you said a stretch.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that the answer is

> 1

Because

> 1 corresponds to a − (a horizontal line) 
>  2 corresponds to = (two horizontal lines) 
>  10 corresponds to + (a horizontal line and a vertical line) 
>  9 corresponds therefore to 1 (a vertical line)

Comment: In terms of methodology, this is the closest to the actual solution although, the 'X' is wrong. The actual solution is very much related to language, a language in particular.

Answer (score 4):

I loved this question and your tags are brilliant.

I have a very similar but different answer that you might like....

rest hidden....

> So I spotted from some slight knowledge of chinnese number characters from the 
>  game Mahjong or Mah-Jong...
>  I thought the answer could be an upside down 4 ... certainly if hand written
>  carefully it could be done.... 
>  [image: looks like the answer and is an upside down 'Western' symbol]
>
>  I like this answer as all the other numbers in the puzzle are 'arabic'

Comment: @NL628 - too bad I didn't see this question earlier - 2 or 3 hours earlier and it would have been more relevant perhaps - still I hope this is an interesting contribution - and many thanks for the welcome

Answer (score 3):

Not quite an answer, more of a comment.

Instead of TWhelan's answer, I would have preferred

> 4

Based off of TheMadHaberdasher's logic,

> Where 10 is +, 1 is -, and 2 is =; Similar to TWelan's answer, which is derived from kanji, I would have assumed the kanji were just upsidedown, hence 4

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! I have noticed that you in fact, do have a different answer, so no need to say its "not quite an answer" :). This is a perfectly good answer; just a little different than the correct one. I hope you have a great time here!

Comment: Thanks! I guess I just don't like posting an answer where 99% of the effort/explanation is the same as an existing one.

Comment: It's fine :))) as long as it is not an exact copy :P

Answer (score 2):

Note: Explanation is for the original version, but the idea does not change, just the notation. Well, taking the hints and the very specific [now deleted] comment...

> I'll assume the space is significant. Thus, 9 ? is not actually a number on it's own, it's 2, similar to 9x. In other words, 9 = 9x, ergo, x = ? = 1.

Comment: I've changed the '?' to 'X' as it was not correctly being displayed in the title, the actual symbol doesn't matter, it is simply a placeholder for the answer.

Comment: @Ambo100 My answer still holds in that case. Care to mention whether it is correct or not?

Comment: Sorry, the answer is incorrect. I had checked what I had written in the body several times but it was unfortunate that when I posted the question, the space between the 9 and ? was cut out. Presumably this is some kind of automated quality filter for questions. I didn't want to have the question title and body differ as that would mislead people from the actual puzzle.

Answer (score 2):

the answer is

> X = 8

because

> Take the last letter of each word in "ten plus one minus two equal nine eight" and you have "nsesolet". These can can be unscrambled to spell the word `noteless`.

Comment: This is not the correct answer but could you explain how the answer for X relates to the word you have?

Comment: Not sure how I can explain it more than I already did.

Answer (score 2):

> I think the answer is 9

because

> 10 + 1 = 101

and

> 101 -2 = 99

Comment: No maths is required to solve this puzzle.

Comment: This answer was already given.

Comment: @gnovice I did not see it

Comment: [Here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/59134/43477).

Answer (score 2):

A two stage, very lateral solution.

We start with

> 10 + 1 − 2 = 9 X Can you solve the puzzle in this solved equation?
>
> You must only replace the 'X' to solve this puzzle. You must not add,
>   remove, rearrange or modify any of the other characters. 'X'
>   represents only one single digit number. No maths is required. The
>   solution relates to language, patterns and lateral thinking.

Then we replace X with:

> 9 (replace all instances of X)

Which leaves us with

> 10 + 1 − 2 = 9 9 Can you solve the puzzle in this solved equation?
>  
>  You must only replace the '9' to solve this puzzle. You must not add,
>  remove, rearrange or modify any of the other characters. '9'
>  represents only one single digit number. No maths is required. The
>  solution relates to language, patterns and lateral thinking.

Then we simplify the left hand side and get

> 9 = 9 9 Can you solve the puzzle in this solved equation?
>  
>  You must only replace the '9' to solve this puzzle. You must not add,
>  remove, rearrange or modify any of the other characters. '9'
>  represents only one single digit number. No maths is required. The
>  solution relates to language, patterns and lateral thinking.

Then we replace

> 9 (all instances of it) with 0 to solve this puzzle as we have
>  0 = 0 Can you solve the puzzle in this solved equation?
>  
>  You must only replace the '0' to solve this puzzle. You must not add,
>  remove, rearrange or modify any of the other characters. '0'
>  represents only one single digit number. No maths is required. The
>  solution relates to language, patterns and lateral thinking.

So yes, I can solve the above equation.

This answer is technically valid, as

> It invovles lateral thinking.
>  It requires no maths (it does require arithmetic, which is very different to maths)
>  It requires language, to know that arithmetic =/= maths

It may not be valid, if

> you consider replacing 10+1-2 with 9 to be adding, removing, rearranging or modifying any of the other characters

Comment: "arithmetic, which is very different to maths" Arithmetic is a part of mathematics. Something that requires no mathematics can't require any part of mathematics.

Comment: @DavidRicherby there are many people who would disagree with you there. Many of these people are mathematicians. 

http://dailycaller.com/2013/06/11/markey-its-really-not-math-its-just-arithmetic/

https://www.reddit.com/r/getdisciplined/comments/3oli7t/needadvice_inability_to_complete_math_courses/

“Arithmetic is to mathematics as spelling is to writing.” is a saying, common enough that I have no idea who to cite as the original.

Go to writers.stackexchange and ask them how to spell a word, see the reception you get.

Comment: Thanks but I'm a mathematician myself. The comparison with spelling is, I'm afraid, nonsense: arithmetic underpins much of mathematics in an intrinsic and unalterable way; speling iz a meer konvenshun.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - whether it is nonsense or not is irrelevant to the question of whether my answer could have been the intended answer to the riddle. It is enough that some people claim to believe that arithmetic is not maths. Unless you can prove beyond all doubt that Ambo100 believes arithmetic to be maths, using information available at the time I posted my answer?

Comment: Fine, if the question does not mean what the question says, then this could be an answer. But the usual assumption is that the question means what it says and that mistakes in the question should be corrected, not exploited. Otherwise you could just answer every question with "A mouse" and claim that the asker expressed the question "What kind of animal was Mickey?" in an incorrect way.

Comment: I am not a mathematician. I have never heard of the claim that arithmetics is not maths. Almost every dictionary definition of arithmetic I can find names arithmetic as a branch of mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

the answer is

> X = 1

because

> 10 + 1 - 2 = 9

same way

> 10 + 1 - 2 = 9 X

Comment: ... What? How does the 1 fit in? (Note: I have myself given 1 as an answer, so I do know at least one way to fit. It's just not clear what you mean)

Answer (score 1):

How about

> 0

Which can be thought of as

> +0  (or -0)

Giving

> 10 + 1 − 2 = 9 + 0 (or 9 - 0)

Answer (score 1):

If you

> count .0 as "representing a single-digit number" (it's a number, though usually written differently, and both as it is and in its usual form it contains just one digit)

then this yields the equation

> 10+1-2 = 9.0

which is true.

Comment: Your answer uses a single-digit number which is good but there is a space between the number 9 and X so the answer would not be quite the same. Remember you cannot adjust any other part of the equation apart from replacing 'X'.

Answer (score 1):

I would say X is

> 9

Because

> 10 + 1 is 101 - 2 is 99

Answer (score 0):

It's either

> 3

because of

> the pattern "1, 2, 3"

or

> 8

because of

> the pattern "10, 9, 8"

.

Comment: The first number is 10, not 1 so the pattern 1, 2, 3 would not work. This puzzle also relates to lateral thinking and language.

Comment: I was thinking of the consecutive 1 and 2 starting from the second number.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your answer.

Answer (score 0):

X is

> 2

Making the sentence

> 10 + 1 − 2 = 9 2

Explanation:

> The sentence is taking two series of numbers from 1 to 10: a series of even numbers (2, 4, 6, 8, 10) alternating with a series of odd numbers (1, 3, 5, 7, 9). The operator + means to raise the previous number by one step, the operator - means to lower the previous number by one step, and the operator = means to keep it the same. Since the series ends at 9 (odd) and 10 (even), 10 + and 9 + are interpreted as 2 and 1 respectively (the series starts from the beginning again). The same is true for 1 - and 2 -, which mean the next number is 9 or 10 respectively.

---

> Therefore, when the sentence says 10 +, the next number in the even series will be 2. When it says 1 -, the next number in the odd series will be 9. When it says 2 =, the next number in the even series will stay the same. After the 9 from the odd series, the next number in the even series is 2.

Comment: 'X' represents only one single digit number, it can not be a mathmatical symbol.

Comment: @Ambo100 Could you take a look at the updated answer?

Comment: I think I understand the explanation but this isn't the answer I'm looking for. The correct solution uses a very simple pattern. This puzzle also relates to lateral thinking and language. The tag wiki for [language](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/language/info) might give a clue.

Answer (score 0):

**10 + 1 − 2 = 9 X**

> I would say that X is 0.
> 10 can be written as "9 + 1" so...
>
> 9 + 1 + 1 - 2
> 9 + 2 - 2
> 9 + 0
> string(9) + string(0)
> 90
>
> So X is 0.

Answer (score 0):

In roman numerals H has been the symbol for 200. Replace X by H and the right side will become 9H which is the hexadecimal representation for 9.

Comment: Where did you find that H stands for roman 200? I've never heard about it, nor does a quick google show anything. In standard notation 200 is CC.

Comment: This is apparently part of "Medieval Roman Numerals"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#Middle_Ages_and_Renaissance

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution that hasn't been tabled yet.

> X is 9 mod 10

which makes the equation:

> 10 + 2 - 1 = 99 mod 10

This passes all rules, but arguably fails "No maths is required". I argue it doesn't, because

> mod can be understood linguistically and in some cases interpreted with visual patterns, and one can see that by definition 9 mod 10 represents 9, and any base 10 number ZN mod 10 (N single digit) also represents N because the Z part can simply be ignored.

Answer (score -1):

Replace 'X" with

> **$\sqrt{1}$**

so it looks like this:

> $10 + 1 − 2 = 9\sqrt{1}$ 
> $9 = 9$

Comment: X can only represent a single digit number with no other formatting, functions or operators.

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer is X = (space)
So, when we replace the X with an space,
it will be

## 10 + 1 − 2 = 9 X

```
10 + 1 − 2 = 9
```

Comment: But the question says 'X' represents a single digit number.

Comment: A blank space represents 0 in some numeral systems.